# OpenCV Install on Macintosh

Tags: macos, opencv

I've been following this tutorial (http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/) to install OpenCV on my Macbook Pro. I have the up-to-date versions of Xcode (6.1.1) and OSX (Yosemite 10.10.1) and have been following the tutorial exactly. However, when trying to make the static libraries with the terminal (Step 2a in the tutorial) I've been getting the following error after running make in the terminal:

```
[  3%] Built target zlib
[  9%] Built target libtiff
[ 16%] Built target libjpeg
[ 24%] Built target libwebp
[ 30%] Built target libjasper
[ 32%] Built target libpng
[ 43%] Built target IlmImf
[ 50%] Built target opencv_core
[ 58%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 60%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 61%] Built target opencv_videoio
[ 61%] Built target opencv_highgui
[ 62%] Built target opencv_ts
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core
ld: library not found for -lgstbase-0.10
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My educated-(ish) guess is that this is a linker error saying that it can't find a certain library it needs in order to make the files since it is able to build the first few targets, but I don't know what library it is, where to find it, or how to get it to link to it, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct. But, the easier way forward most probably is not to find the library, just to reconfigure `cmake` files so that, the library is not needed.

`gstbase-0.10` is searched since you have checked `WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10`. GStreamer is for audio video processing. Hoping if you didn't include that library on purpose, you won't need it. Uncheck that checkbox in `cmake-gui`, and click `Configure` and then `Generate` as in screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't check BUILD_TBB, WITH_FFMPEG or WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10 in your CMAKE configuration, but you can check WITH_TBB if installed.