# OpenCv Install Trouble

Tags: opencv

I'm try to install openCV on my mac, but after running brew install opencv I get this error:

```
Devins-MacBook-Air:~ devinwieker$ brew install opencv 
==> Installing opencv from homebrew/homebrew-science
==> Installing dependencies for opencv: gcc, readline, sqlite, gdbm, python, eigen, ilmbase,
==> Installing opencv dependency: gcc
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.9.2/gcc-4.9.2.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc-4.9.2.tar.bz2
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1 --libdir=
==> make bootstrap
make[3]: *** [cc1plus] Error 1
rm gcc.pod
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I haven't tried brew. If not relunctant to use `cmake-gui`, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27735370/1180117 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/28122457/1180117 might help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I tried using "brew doctor" which you should definitely try, and if that was not helpful try updating Xcode and its developer tools.